# Reviewed same post twice in the same review queue

Tags: bug, review

I was reviewing Late Answers on SO when I found out that the previous post that I reviewed was the same exact one I was reviewing now. It seemed weird as you can only do this in two ***different*** review queues. I thought I would see this as a once-in-a-lifetime thing that will be later be posted on meta.SO.

Nope, it happened on Coffee SE as well, reviewing back-to-back posts that were the same in the same review queue and only counting as 1 review.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I went out of the review queue and forgot to link... Sorry!

Comment: So check your review history?

Comment: Links or didn't happen

Comment: I'm currently banned for a month...

Comment: As I said, they counted as one

Comment: Which browser? Any weird ISP? Hideous userscripts?

Comment: Google Chrome and nothing weird or out of the ordinary